# Reduce array of DOM elements to the ones with the deepest level in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's assume i have HTML markup like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <p class="foo">text</p>
        <p class="bar">more <span>text</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let's further assume that i selected some of them in an array of DOM elements:

```
var allElements = jQuery('div,p').get();
// result: [div#content, div#sidebar, div#main, p.foo, p.bar]
```

Now i want to efficiently remove all elements from the result set which have a child in the result. In other words, only the deepest level should remain. So, the desired result would be:

```
var deepestElements = doSomethingWith(allElements);
// desired result: [div#sidebar, p.foo, p.bar]
```

**How can i do this?**

By the way: "Deepest elements" seems to be the wrong term for what i am trying to do. Is there any better name?

Comment: Are you essentially looking for the tips of your branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution ([JQuery distinct descendants (filter out all parents in result set)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152739/675065)).

Code credits to [cfedermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330959/cfedermann):

```
jQuery.fn.distinctDescendants = function() {
    var nodes = [];
    var parents = [];

    // First, copy over all matched elements to nodes.
    jQuery(this).each(function(index, Element) {
        nodes.push(Element);
    });

    // Then, for each of these nodes, check if it is parent to some element.
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        var node_to_check = nodes[i];
        jQuery(this).each(function(index, Element) {

            // Skip self comparisons.
            if (Element == node_to_check) {
                return;
            }

            // Use .tagName to allow .find() to work properly.
            if((jQuery(node_to_check).find(Element.tagName).length > 0)) {
                if (parents.indexOf(node_to_check) < 0) {
                    parents.push(node_to_check);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Finally, construct the result.
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        var node_to_check = nodes[i];
        if (parents.indexOf(node_to_check) < 0) {
            result.push(node_to_check);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `.filter` and use `.children().length` to filter out. See below,

```
var deepestElements = jQuery('div,p').filter(function () {  
                         return ($(this).children().length == 0);
                       });
```

Comment: This won't work because the "deepest elements" may contain children elements. They are not always leafes. In the example, this would remove `p.bar` because it has a `span`child, but i need it in the result.

Comment: @Alp How about `return (($(this).children('div, p').length == 0));`. That would work for above example but doesn't really check for "deepest" condition you are looking for.

Comment: I can't use a specific selector like `'div, p'` in the `.children()` method, it needs to be dynamic. I need a way to pass the complete current jQuery object to the filter, so that i can pass that to the `.children()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes as SKS suggested use this

```
jQuery('div,p').filter(function(){
    if($(this).children('div, p').length==0) 
        return true;
    })
```

here the only change is that in children I only look for div and p child nodes... and skip others like span in this case...

Hope this solves your issue...

**UPDATE**

as you are expecting hope this helps

```
var types_to_check = 'div,p';
jQuery(types_to_check).filter(function(){
    if($(this).children(types_to_check).length==0) 
        return true;
    })
```

wouldnt this work?

Comment: I can't use a specific selector like `'div, p'` in the `.children()` method, it needs to be dynamic. I need a way to pass the complete current jQuery object to the filter, so that i can pass that to the `.children()` method.

Comment: No. First of all, `.children()` only checks for direct children, not for all descendants, we need `.find()` for that. Second, `types_to_check` needs to be a jquery object, but [that does not seem to work either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152627/jquery-distinct-descendants-filter-out-all-parents-in-result-set).