# JQuery distinct descendants (filter out all parents in result set)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, filter

I [needed a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094743/reduce-array-of-dom-elements-to-the-ones-with-the-deepest-level-in-javascript) to filter out all elements that are parents of other elements in the result set. I tried to write a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.distinctDescendants = function() {
    var nodes = [];
    var result = this;

    jQuery(result).each(function() {
        var node = jQuery(this).get(0);
        if(jQuery(node).find(result).length == 0) {
            nodes.push(node);
        }
    });

    return nodes;
};
```

When i run the following command on [this example page](http://www.maquinastudio.com/contact/):

```
jQuery('body, textarea').distinctDescendants();
```

I get the (wrong) result:

```
[body.contact-page, textarea, textarea]
```

This is wrong because body is the parent of at least one other element in the result (both textareas). Therefore the expected result would be:

```
[textarea, textarea]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Post the sample HTML or Create Jsfiddle for that

Comment: `this` is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using `jQuery('body > input')` instead?

You can use the following (verbose) code to achieve what you want; it should work as drop-in replacement of your plugin code.

```
jQuery.fn.distinctDescendants = function() {
    var nodes = [];
    var parents = [];

    // First, copy over all matched elements to nodes.
    jQuery(this).each(function(index, Element) {
        nodes.push(Element);
    });

    // Then, for each of these nodes, check if it is parent to some element.
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        var node_to_check = nodes[i];
        jQuery(this).each(function(index, Element) {

            // Skip self comparisons.
            if (Element == node_to_check) {
                return;
            }

            // Use .tagName to allow .find() to work properly.
            if((jQuery(node_to_check).find(Element.tagName).length > 0)) {
                if (parents.indexOf(node_to_check) < 0) {
                    parents.push(node_to_check);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Finally, construct the result.
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        var node_to_check = nodes[i];
        if (parents.indexOf(node_to_check) < 0) {
            result.push(node_to_check);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: the method needs to be dynamic. the jquery object could be a chain of complex selectors.

Comment: Your update does exactly what i needed. Thank you very much! Although i don't understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You are not using the tagName inside .find and you have to systematically compare all nodes to all potential children nodes (hence the two loops). Glad I could help.

Comment: i see, thanks for clarification. the jquery documentation may be wrong at this point because it says that jquery objects are allowed as parameter in `.find()` calls.

Comment: I created a fiddle with a working example, if anyone is interested: http://jsfiddle.net/yZgBL/

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems OK but your example is perhaps wrong. You said -

`jQuery('body, input').distinctDescendants();`

I get the (wrong) result:

```
[body.contact-page, textarea, textarea]
```

How come you are getting textarea if that is not there in the selector?
Also be careful using this method. Remember -

jQuery('div, input').distinctDescendants(); means some input are inside the div under consideration and some are outside. Though the result is not unpredictable but it is apparently difficult to guess. So most of the time try use selector having class name or id.

Do let us know your feedback ... I feel the function is ok.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake in my example, i corrected it to `jQuery('body, textarea').distinctDescendants();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting for

```
jQuery('body, input').filter(function(){if($(this).children().length >0) return false; else return true; })
```

or may be rather

```
jQuery('body, input, textarea').filter(function(){if($(this).children().length >0) return false; else return true; })
```

and this will return only the text areas(as you want in the example)

```
jQuery('body, textarea').filter(function(){if($(this).children().length >0) return false; else return true; })
```

**UPDATE**

so you want something like this

```
var elems = 'textarea';

jQuery('body, '+ elems )
      .filter(function(){
           if($(this).find(elems ).length >0) 
               return false; 
           else return true; 
       })
```

which returns

```
[textarea, textarea]
```

Comment: or can you give me what result you expect from jQuery('body, input').distinctDescendants();....................or may be..................from jQuery('body, input, textarea').distinctDescendants();......that might help here

Comment: 'body,input,textarea' should return all inputs and textareas. But i should make a better example. Also, `.children()` is not working for second or higher-level descendants, only for direct children